# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'DEFAULT_SCONFIG_FILENAME' public_html/Maged/Connect.php on line 167

Tags: error

I try to make a backup with filezilla and i think i have move a folder.

here is the error i get
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'DEFAULT_SCONFIG_FILENAME' in /home/swell/public_html/Maged/Connect.php on line 167

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The folder `Maged` should not be in the root. It goes on the `downloader` folder.